# Android activity to show a directory explorer to browse content of sdcard

Tags: android

In android, is there an activity show a directory explorer to browse content of sdcard ?
Like a File explorer in Java, it can show the content of current directory and I can move up to its parent by clicking '..' and move down to a child directory by clicking the name of the child directory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get u started [Choose File Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog/3645048#3645048)