# Choose folder on Android device

Tags: android, android-intent, file-manager

I would like to let user pick directory and save downloaded file (my app downloads file). 
 I know that some tools (for example, ES File Explorer) provide such intent-filters.
see http://www.estrongs.com/en/support/developers.html. I start activity for result and then get selected folder as a result.

Also, I know that there are no "select folder" intent standards (I can't use the same intent with other tools). Do you know other tools to support such functionality ? I would like to let user use his tool, not ES File Manager.

Also, does Astro provide such intent filters? I can't find this info on their page. (I think astro is the most used file manager for android)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this question? I have a similar question.

Comment: No, didn't find a solution yet

Comment: An answer to a related question over here http://stackoverflow.com/q/6656987/853220

Comment: Another related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6983843/853220

Comment: You need to override onCreateDialog.
That post may help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587325/how-to-select-folder-in-android

Answer (score 2):

I've recently come across something that might potentially help here:
http://www.openintents.org/en/node/159

It has a demo application showing how it can interact with third party applications as a file/directory picker.

That said, I have not tried it yet. I stumbled across this question as I am still looking for other options.

Edit: actually, it looks very similar to your ES File Manager link. Perhaps it is merely a clone.

Comment: Yes, It's almost the same. I don't understand why all file managers do not handle the same intent to do this

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete Android library: https://github.com/lemberg/directory-selector-dialog-preference

It can be used either as DialogFragment or as DialogPreference. I am it's author so don't hesitate to ask any questions.