# Call the list of File Managers from the mobile application

Tags: android

My Android application is accessing the SDCard.

I have developed the source code to display the folder & files on the SDCard.

Currently, I want to provide the option where the user can view the SDCard Folder/File structure using the File Managers(Astro Manager , Linda Manager) already installed on the user's Android mobile device.

How can I call or provide the list of options of the file managers to the user.

Any hints/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Astro and linda are applications you can open this app and view files and folders. if your are developing code for file explore you give the  menu to choose which one to open.

Comment: In the menu itself , how to call the list of File managers available on the Android device ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add this line in manifest file.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.android.ui.DocumentModuleActivity"
                android:value="MWare" />

            <intent-filter android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <action android:name="com.android.ui.DocumentModuleActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <data android:scheme="file"   />
               <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.las" />
            </intent-filter>
```

for [more refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656987/android-intent-filter-custom-filetype)

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I am being redirected within the Astro Manager. I should display the list of File Managers , then the user can select from the list . Kindly provide your hints/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code for OI Filemanager:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Or you use the VIEW Intent with the mimetype