# New ASTRO File Manager (Android) broken with ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Tags: android

UPDATED: the successive version of  ASTRO File Manager (Android) works again with ACTION_GET_CONTENT!

---

Did anyone notice that the new version of ASTRO File Manager (Android) is broken with ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

This code used to work well to choose a zipfile with previous versions of ASTRO File Manager, and now it does not seem to work anymore. It shows only directories, and no files.

```
Intent importTree = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
importTree.setType("file/*");
Intent c = Intent.createChooser(importTree, "Select zip file");
startActivityForResult(c, IMPORT_TREE);
```

The code still works with other file managers like OI File Manager (Open Intents).