# How to select folder in android?

Tags: android, directory, android-widget, picker, filechooser

Hi there is a way to select folder where user want to save file in android . I check out http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/

it has functionality to select file but i want to select folder , please provide me usable link or examples.

Comment: you can create dir programatically

Comment: I suggest you to create your own file/folder picker and call it with intents. It is a bit tedious but you are in control of your code and you can call it from you future applications. Otherwise look for a 3rd party filexplorer that has a public API via Intents.

Comment: Sad that this isn't built in. How many versions of Android have there been and none of their developers thought people would want to select a folder 
- I'm hugely confused Ted :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same source in my app (pretty sure), and there is a block of code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        selectButton.setEnabled(false);
        if (file.canRead()) {
            lastPositions.put(currentPath, position);
            getDir(path.get(position));
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setTitle(
                            "[" + file.getName() + "] "
                                    + getText(R.string.cant_read_folder))
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {

                                }
                            }).show();
        }
    } else {
        selectedFile = file;
        v.setSelected(true);
        selectButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

You just have to edit how it handle's `if (file.isDirectory())`. I would recommend declaring a `boolean` value in your Activity which you change to `true` if the file is a directory and it is already false. Then if said value is true, then traverse the directory. Also when you change said value to `true`, you would need to call `selectButton.setEnabled(true)`. This would be quite a bit less complicated than making your own code, I would say.

Comment: if (file.isDirectory()) {selectedFile = file;  v.setSelected(true);selectButton.setEnabled(true);
if (file.canRead()) {   lastPositions.put(currentPath, position);
getDir(path.get(position));} else {new AlertDialog.Builder(this)  .setIcon(R.drawable.icon).setTitle(     "[" + file.getName() + "] "+ getText(R.string.cant_read_folder))     .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,          int which) {        }        }).show();}
} else {      v.setSelected(false);   selectButton.setEnabled(false);}

Comment: I have modified function as above  , but i want to select folder in place of file , it return previous directory when i traverse directory hierarchy.

Comment: @SushantBhatnagar can you show the modified function for directory?

Answer (score 1):

How about using [OI File Manager](http://openintents.org/en/filemanager)? This App has the following Intents: `PICK_FILE`, `PICK_DIRECTORY`.
There is even sample code on the page for using the Intents.

Comment: I think question aims for solution integrated, not using external application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28479561/779140
I am mentioned library author so don't hesitate to ask any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and I end up using  [**NoNonsense-FilePicker**](https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker)

Add to gradle file

> compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:4.0.0'

Trigger file/folder/dir pick

```
try {

                    Utils.makeHepticFeedback(getActivity());

                    Intent selectDirectoyIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FilePickerActivity.class);
                    selectDirectoyIntent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
                    selectDirectoyIntent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_ALLOW_CREATE_DIR, true);
                    selectDirectoyIntent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_MODE, FilePickerActivity.MODE_DIR);
                    selectDirectoyIntent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_START_PATH, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
                    startActivityForResult(selectDirectoyIntent, FILE_CODE);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "exception", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Handle Activity result to get selected file or files

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);


                // NOW WE HAVE OUR WANTED STRING
                if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                    System.out
                            .println("selectedImagePath is the right one for you!");

                    PreferenceHelper.getPreferenceHelperInstance().setString(getActivity(),
                            PreferenceHelper.PLAYER_BACKGROUND,
                            selectedImageUri.toString());

                    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(Uri.parse(
                            PreferenceHelper.getPreferenceHelperInstance().getString(getActivity(),
                                    PreferenceHelper.PLAYER_BACKGROUND
                                    , AppConstants.DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_URL))).
                            into((ImageView) ButterKnife.findById(getActivity(), R.id.play_back));

                }
            } else if (requestCode == FILE_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                if (null != data && !data.getBooleanExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false)) {
                    // The URI will now be something like content://PACKAGE-NAME/root/path/to/file
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    // A utility method is provided to transform the URI to a File object
                    File file = com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.Utils.getFileForUri(uri);
                    // If you want a URI which matches the old return value, you can do
                    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    // Do something with the result...

                    Snackbar.make(fileFormat, "Recording folder updated to" + fileUri.getPath() + " ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ ", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    AppConfig.RECORDING_FOLDER = fileUri.getPath();

                    PreferenceHelper.getPreferenceHelperInstance().setString(getActivity(), PreferenceHelper.RECORDING_FOLDER, AppConfig.RECORDING_FOLDER);

                    setUpSettingValue();

                } else {

                    // Handling multiple results is one extra step
                    ArrayList<String> paths = data.getStringArrayListExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_PATHS);
                    if (paths != null) {
                        for (String path : paths) {
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
                            // Do something with the URI
                            File file = com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.Utils.getFileForUri(uri);
                            // If you want a URI which matches the old return value, you can do
                            Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                            // Do something with the result...

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Selected dir" + fileUri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: `Utils.makeHepticFeedback(getActivity());` method not found. If I comment that, I'm getting an Exception
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.app/com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.FilePickerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageButton`

Any idea?

Comment: Utils.makeHepticFeedback(getActivity()) is method to make device vibrate and give a button feel it have nothing to do with file picker. You can comment it. It seems like a UI issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448999/error-inflating-class-imagebutton