# Input and output path in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG to make a video editor. I stuck when selecting a folder:

1/ I will show "File Manager" to user. They can choose a folder then return a path. How can choose a folder and get its path. For example: /sdcard/videokit/.

[image]

Here is my code, I must choose a mp4 file (not a folder I want).

```
public void openFolder()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        + "/sdcard/");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "folder|video/mp4");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Folder"),PICK_VIDEO_OUTPUT_REQUEST);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your 1) is not clear. What can change? Isn't it a fixed path?

Comment: 2) is answered here: _[Get filename and path from uri from mediastore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)_

Comment: My 1) is that I will show "File Manager". User can choose a folder and it will return a folder path for me. Thank you for your comment, I will edit my post to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use Intent to choose folder in Android. You need a dialog of your own. Luckily, there are plenty ready to use code samples available, e.g. [How to select folder in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587325/how-to-select-folder-in-android).