# Error inflating class ImageButton

Tags: android, android-resources, android-imagebutton, inflate-exception, binary-xml

I have an app which has `fragment` and `image button` on that. The problem is it's working on and above `5.0` but not below 5.0. The min sdk version is 17.

Not getting what's wrong here. I am getting 2 exceptions.

One is `RuntimeException` for `image button`.
Second is `ResourceNotFoundException` for fab selector file.

Log :
1st exception --

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16:

Error inflating class `ImageButton`

2nd exception --

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16:
>   Error inflating class ImageButton

On line :

`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);`   of main fragment.

**Main fragment :**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private CharSequence Titles[]={"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"};
    private int Numboftabs =7;
    private SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    private Intent i;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        setupUI(view);
        return view;
    }
    void setupUI(View view)
    {
        FrameLayout fab = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.main_fab);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_fab);


        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String day;
                Boolean editMode = false;

                if(tabs.getCurrentTab() == 0)
                {
                    day = "Mon";
                    i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("day",day);
                    i.putExtra("EditMode",editMode);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
                else if(tabs.getCurrentTab() == 1)
                {
                    day = "Tue";
                    i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("day",day);
                    i.putExtra("EditMode",editMode);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else if(tabs.getCurrentTab() == 2)
                {
                    day = "Wed";
                    i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("day",day);
                    i.putExtra("EditMode",editMode);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else if(tabs.getCurrentTab() == 3)
                {
                    day = "Thu";
                    i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("day",day);
                    i.putExtra("EditMode",editMode);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                else if(tabs.getCurrentTab() == 4)
                {
                    day = "Fri";
                    i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("day",day);
                    i.putExtra("EditMode",editMode);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else if(tabs.getCurrentTab() == 5)
                {
                    day = "Sat";
                    i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("day",day);
                    i.putExtra("EditMode",editMode);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                else if(tabs.getCurrentTab() == 6)
                {
                    day = "Sun";
                    i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("day",day);
                    i.putExtra("EditMode",editMode);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                Log.d("tab",tabs.getCurrentTab() + "");
            }
        });


        mAdapter =  new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_scroll_color);
            }
        });
        tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }

}
```

Fab selector :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Fragment main :

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.adgatemedia.offerwallsdk.fragments.MainFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <utils.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">

            <include layout="@layout/myfab"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Fab :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_fab"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/myfab_shadow"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_shadow"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtn_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_selector"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_36dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/fab_elevation_selector" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Full stack trace :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class ImageButton
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class ImageButton
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:33)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/fab_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020081
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1953)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:59)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:55)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:171)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:33) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:967)
02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
```

Can you please let me know what's wrong here?

Comment: Post the full stack trace, not a partial please.

Comment: please check edited question.@Gabe Sechan

Comment: Can you please check which folder contains `fab_selector`?

Comment: Its drawable folder.@MustansarSaeed

Comment: what is your @animator/fab_elevation_selector

Comment: its a xml file for animation of fab. @KDeogharkar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This exception

> 02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout
>   E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Can't convert to color: type=0x2 02-17 05:42:39.445
>   3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326) 02-17
>   05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:967)
>   02-17 05:42:39.445 3247-3247/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)

leads to the conclusion that this line `<solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />` in `fab_selector` is the culprit. Try to change `color` to `HEX value` and then test.

hope this helps.

Comment: As i have themes in my application so I have not given hex value. and it runs on 5.0 and above. why so? @Mustansar Saeed

Comment: It may be the case that Post Lollipop APIs handle these operations but pre-lollipop does not contain these functions. Just a wild guess :)

Comment: This is not really an "answer".  It should be possible to use this theme attribute as shown if it's defined.

Comment: But then how can I change color of fab on theme change ? If I provide hex value it wont change right? @Mustnsar Saeed

Comment: @DougStevenson: Sid can confirm if it solved his problem.

Comment: @Sid: You can create different resource files for Pre-Lollipop and Post-Lollipop for the `colors` and then use color from those files

Comment: great this worked... But I dint get how can I use different resource file? The fab selector would only be one and if I have 3 themes then 3 different accent colors..How to apply to this? @MustansarSaeed

Comment: and same I have applied to toolbar. How dose that work and not this?@MustansarSaeed

Comment: create different `colors.xml` files for `values`, `values-v14` and `values-v21` for pre and post lollipop devices

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You need to create a folder like 'drawable-v21'.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced this problem but I solved it.

In my case the error was that the png image I imported for ImageButton was saved in drawable-v24 automatically by android studio . I copied the png from there and pasted it into drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

this being a top result on google I wanted to share what solved the same error for me (although not the same issue as above)

- make sure build tools version is up to date
- I had the combination of an vector src drawable and a elevation value (API 21+ only) which seemed to trip it up. I made a separate layout for v21 to have the elevation value (but kept the vector drawable everywhere) and this solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

The format of the image.png was not OK.
My solution:
I installed greenshot on my PC to grab an image from my screen
https://getgreenshot.org/
Then I saved the image as png file in my res/drawable.
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Solved mine (`rounded_corner_image_view.xml (v24)`):

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_image_view"
```

My background drawable was **v24**. Created a lower drawable and viola