# Using intent from other application

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to display a "select folder" intent in my android app and therefore use the OpenIntents FileManager intent (see [Choose folder on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793001/choose-folder-on-android-device) and http://www.openintents.org/en/node/165).

As far as I understand, this means that the OI File Manager (.apk) must be installed on the device (at least the Demo from the SVN repository doesn't open the Intent until the OI File Manager was started). What is a common way of achieving this? Is there any way to automatically install an .apk for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go through the **GitHub** project [**mburman / Android-File-Explore**](https://github.com/mburman/Android-File-Explore). A one java file, integrate it with your project so no need to use any third party file manager application and don't worry for install it `.apk` file. Use **FileManager** functionality with your own code..