# folder path picker for android

Tags: android, file-io, directory

my app needs to access a folder the user separately downloads. i would like the user to be able to 'pick' or browse to the folder through my app to get its path. the path could be internal storage or external storage sd card. since me is a noob, is there a very easy way to do this?? thanx :)
steps:

1. user install app
2. user downloads a folder and saves it on device (could be anywhere)
3. user shows the folder path to app, through a folder browser/folder picker type thingy (how do i do this?)
4. app starts work, evr1s happy :)

and yes, this is the only way it has to work.. no other workarounds pls. thanx again..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I got it. Using chose file Dialog. Here is what you need ,[Choose File Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog)

And here

http://www.streamhead.com/android-tutorial-sd-card/

Another way is that put all yours file in downloads dir into `ListView` using `File.getlistfiles`. And you manage you file in there.

Comment: this is file picker, not folder