# Android, how to choose save file location?

Tags: android, android-file

is there any solution how to choose the saving files location? 
maybe with the original file browser, to choose the destination?

thank you!

Comment: Do you want to save a file using your app?

Comment: yes, it's record a video and after the stop button(maybe before) wwant the choose where to save it

Comment: I think you should look at the internal/external storage on this page : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choose File Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need is [Android Directory Picker](http://www.bgreco.net/directorypicker/)

Answer (score 3):

Better to save files with your app namespace:

```
String extStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
path = extStorage+"/Android/data/com.mydomain.myapp/";
```

It will be deleted when app gets uninstalled.

Here is actually everything about data storing.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

From the above link:

> If you're using API Level 7 or lower, use
>   `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, to open a `File` representing the
>   root of the external storage. You should then write your data in the
>   following directory:
>
> ```
> /Android/data/<package_name>/files/
> ```

Comment: i know how to save it it works (mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/Festivale.mp4");) but want the choose the directory

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest and expected to save this out to the dedicated area on the external SD card.

You can get this folder by calling

file://localhost/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/docs/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

You can also append a sub-folder to reference the source better ie. your app.

You can either choose DIRECTORY_PICTURES or DIRECTORY_MOVIES. If it's user created I'd probably stick to pictures.

To be helpful you can also call the media scanner to add it to the appropriate content provider system wide.

```
sendBroadcast( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
                    Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))
        );
```

If you MUST get a file chooser going, which isn't the recomened approach to expose the user to the file system. Try the file chooser form Open Intents. http://www.openintents.org/en/node/164

Comment: alright, so no theres no way to make something like save file dialog or somthing:

Comment: edit, added reference to open intents file chooser. Although this will prompt the user to download the file chooser, but its pretty streamlined last time I was exposed to it http://www.openintents.org/en/node/164

Comment: There are more `Environment` constants -  [`Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), for example.