# Select custom location to save file

Tags: android

I have just 2 weeks of experience in android and  want to do something for which i have no idea how to do this.My requirement is like that i want to save and read file in my app not on fixed location but on location where user wants to save and retrieve just like in UC browser when we download the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Android Directory Picker](http://www.bgreco.net/directorypicker/) for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848224/android-how-to-choose-save-file-location?answertab=active#tab-top