# android - simple file chooser needed

Tags: android

For my current app, I need to add a file chooser. The user should be able to choose a single file from the sdcard. So far I found

http://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser

which is terrific, yet I don't like that user have to double tap to choose a file, I'm afraid the user won't get it if they don't catch the toast explaining it. (I missed it the first time ...) So I was wondering

- Am I allowed to modify the source code and use the modified version in my non open source project?
- Is there any other good file chooser available?

**UPDATE**

Lai Vung, the author of this awesome library has just released a new version of it in which (single) file selection is done via single tap. Great

Comment: Hi, I've been writing that library. In short, feel free to make changes and use it in your (commercial) apps. You can find it in the file `NOTICE` at root dir of the library. And about Apache License v2.0… I'm not sure, but I chose it just because… Android uses it. Also thanks to @jconfus jconfus. His answer is great. Another example: Google Drive uses some libraries under Apache License v2.0, and that app is closed source. Some friends have same problems as yours (double/ single tap), I will add single tap feature to next version. Thank you for using the library and for the feedback  :-)

Comment: Thank you so much Lia for responding and offering your awesome library so generously for reuse. For now I just call the double tap method from the single tap method in the case it is a file so that works well. If it will become a feature of future versions that would be great. Once more thanks a lot for the spirit of sharing.

Comment: Thanks for your nice words. You're welcome  :-)

Comment: Hi, I've upgraded the library. Hope it could help you…

Comment: great - I will let you know how it goes ,-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choose File Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog)

Comment: The link appears to be dead. Another project (https://code.google.com/p/android-file-chooser/) seems similar but does not appear to be what was originally referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the android-filechooser uses Apache License 2.0, you can read it [here](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)

And the answer to your specific question is in the FAQ [here] (http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#IsItFee)

which says:
"Is there a fee for using Apache software in a commercial product?
No. We do not distinguish between personal, internal, or commercial use of our software. Packaging and redistribution of any of it is subject to the terms of our license , however."

a bit more 
http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN

**"I'm not a lawyer. What does it all MEAN?**

Describing legal documents in non-legalese is fraught with potential for misinterpretation. Notwithstanding the text that follows, the actual text of the license itself is legally binding and authoritative.

That said, here's what the Apache license says in layman's terms:

**It allows you to:**

***freely download and use Apache software, in whole or in part, for personal, company internal, or commercial purposes;***

use Apache software in packages or distributions that you create.

**It forbids you to:**

redistribute any piece of Apache-originated software without proper attribution;

use any marks owned by The Apache Software Foundation in any way that might state or imply that the Foundation endorses your distribution;

use any marks owned by The Apache Software Foundation in any way that might state or imply that you created the Apache software in question.

**It requires you to:**

include a copy of the license in any redistribution you may make that includes Apache software;

provide clear attribution to The Apache Software Foundation for any distributions that include Apache software.

**It does not require you to:**

include the source of the Apache software itself, or of any modifications you may have made to it, in any redistribution you may assemble that includes it;

submit changes that you make to the software back to the Apache Software Foundation (though such feedback is encouraged)."

Comment: Thanks jconfus - i am always confused about Licenses so I wanted to get this clarified, thanks a lot.

Comment: me too :) LGPL, Mozilla, GPL, BSD, MIT, Apache, too many !

Comment: decided to go for android-filechooser with some minor modifications, thanks for make the wrong license concerns fade ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could take a look at **OpenIntents OI File Manager**.

The OpenIntents file manager allows you to browse your SD card, create directories, rename, move, and delete files. It also acts as an extension to other applications to display "Open" and "Save" dialogs.

http://openintents.org/en/filemanager

Third party developers can use OI File Manager through simple intents to present an "Open file", "Save file", or "Select folder" activity.

The file manager features PICK_FILE and PICK_DIRECTORY intents:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Link/download for code:
https://github.com/openintents/filemanager

Comment: Thanks chrkad - does the user need to install the apk to use this file manager or can I use the source coide and integrate it directly into my app (or use it as a library)?

Comment: I think you can integrate it with modifying the source code, but if not, it will be installed as a separate component (APK).

Comment: thx - i wont want to ask the user to install a separate component - just checking the app at the moment

Comment: seems like the whole idea behind open intent is that the apps are installed separately - makes sense just for my app it is too much in order to get a simple file chooser done