# Phone file uploader

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, file-upload

I am writing a small application in jquery mobile and phonegap to upload file (doc, pdf, or txt and not image) from card to server.

Images I can upload using

```
navigator.camera.getPicture()
```

which trigger gallery and i can select image and upload.

but at a different place I need to upload doc, pdf or txt files, i wish i can trigger file browser somehow and select file from there.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the input type="file"?.I think it supports file upload from internal storage but not external sd

Comment: input type file do not work with phonegap

Answer (score 0):

[FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) is an object that allows you to upload files to a server or download files from a server.

Use in conjunction with [FileSystem](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileSystem), or play around with `mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA` option of [`getPicture`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions) perhaps.

Comment: Thanks soulseekah... but i need to trigger "File browser" of some kind to reach to file... i am stuck there :(

Comment: There is no such thing in Cordova/Phonegap, you'll have to implement it yourself. There's no standard file select dialog in the SDK even, for inspiration you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog, http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/ and wrap it into a Phonegap/Cordova plugin, which you can then opensource and maybe have it added to Phonegap/Cordova core.