# What permission is required?

Tags: android, sdk, permissions

In my android html app there is a "Choose File"

Well when i click on it nothing happens
App name "Share File"

i think it requires a permission
I searched google and didn't find anything

Please can anyone tell me what's the required permission?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri1Fx.png

Comment: You need to implement something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3645048/786337

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean to take a file from the phone:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: the line above activates both, WRITE and READ.
But to be sure, I used WRITE to include both, no idea what the purpose of the rest of his app is.

Comment: the html contains File: <input type="file" name="photo" size="50MB">

Answer (score 0):

i think you required below permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: the html contains  File: <input type="file" name="photo" size="50MB">

Answer (score 0):

check the file chooser example from here.. 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/