# android java - Save file dialog GUI

Tags: java, android, file

I am looking for a simple gui based save file dialog for Android java.
I am developing my first Android app which is a PDF merger which I already have a open dialog which I got from [Choose File Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog.The) answer must support Android Ice Cream Sandwich and up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android does not provide any native save/open dialog. However, you may use [this library](https://github.com/RustamG/file-dialogs) to create an open and save dialog.

Comment: @Adnam I've seen https://goo.gl/photos/LeEHw6pQZiqnUEgc8 in apps and Android

Comment: Click on internal storage in left side menu

Comment: @Adnam https://goo.gl/photos/nNgGLL7VnC5cUjoE7

Comment: So that is it, you are seeing the storage, select the location where you want to save the file or the file you want to open. :)

Comment: https://goo.gl/photos/uL62J1DkWkqJaU358