# Android HTML accept tag for file selecting

Tags: android, filefilter

I have a button that when pressed opens a file dialogue. I want to filter the files available for selection to just: `pdf, docx, html, rtf and txt`.

I have been trying to use the html accept tag, but compared to the desktop version the android one seems a little bit weirder, for example `pdfs` can be filtered with `application/pdf` but not `.pdf` and `text/*` allows nearly all files but `.txt` does not work.

Does any one have a guide for filtering with html in Android, all I can find is how to use `image/*` or `audio/*` which is not useful.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog

Comment: not rally I have to do it though the html as its a web application so it is runing JavaScript. 
I got to this point
 <input type="file" id="file" accept="text/rtf,text/html,text/plain,application/pdf" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left: 0;right:0;opacity: 0.001">
but the line just refuses to work on android.

Comment: A so you are using a WebView? Do you load an html file into the WebView? Does the hole application need to be html?

Comment: I am translating a web application to Android using a cordova build, but file filter is not working on android, I know you can filter using html "accept" tag. e.g.
` accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,text/rtf,text/html,text/plain,application/pdf" `
but for me its not working the commas just seem to break it